# How to insert leading zero into database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

So I am try to insert data which is a Identity Card Number, so the in front of the number is 000301-01-0999
when I insert it into the Database the zero in front of the value is disappear and became 301-01-0999,It suppose to be 6-2-4 digit
I tried to solved it with this code

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IC.ToString().PadLeft(12, '0'))
```

Comment: you have to store it as a string.

Comment: What is the datatype of the column in sql you are storing the card number?

Comment: So let's look at the value you desire - 0000301-01-0999. That is 15 characters, correct? But you wrote "6-2-4" while your example is "7-2-4". What you did find in the database (presumably) is 11 characters - suspiciously close to the padding length (12) in your statement. But padding does not add dashes so there must be more code involved - which we cannot see or debug.

Comment: @Fenr1r絶, feel free to answer your own question, which is [100% allowed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250204/can-you-answer-your-own-questions-on-stack-overflow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this line of code and it works just what I wanted, so the database had the value which is **123456789** so I wanted a 12 digit value , I inserted this code then It will became **000123456789** which is what I wanted

```
@Convert.ToInt32(item.IC).ToString().PadLeft(12, '0')
```